# text direction right to left (rtl) inside popover bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I try to code a simple popover that appears on hover, pretty easy so far.
the problem is that I want to write the title not in English in fact I want to write the title in Hebrew. As you all know the direction of the language is rtl and not ltr. My problem is that I cant change the direction of the text property, already tried to use class= pull-right.

here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#start').popover({
    html : true, 
    content: "as you can see the hebrew text doesnt fit the title",
    title: "<div class='pull-right'>שלום</div>",
    placement : "bottom",
    trigger: "hover"


    });   


});
```

here is the link [to test the code](http://www.bootply.com/DfaLPXH9oh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the div tag around שלום, and write in your css:

```
.popover-title {text-align: right;}
```

Here is your [example](http://www.bootply.com/UDKGyQ8j0g)

Comment: awesome it's working, but what if I want one title to be rtl and one title that is written in English I want to be ltr

Comment: you could create a data-style attribute for each one, like [this](http://www.bootply.com/iKH5FnZH3y) and change the attribute for the one you want.

Comment: got another question... how to change the arrow color?

Comment: you need to change the border color on the .arrow:after. You can inspect the layout on [link](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) if you have a doubt.